# JSF reducing field supplication in Backing Bean being with with filed annotations in it

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces

I'm not expert in JSF..

There is a bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ClientBean
```

Also the code has class `Client` (not a bean. just a class)

Actually `ClientBean` duplicate all fields from `Client`. What's not good. Duplication I mean itself.

It seems the reason of duplication is to provide the annotations over the fields that `ClientBean` duplicates/has. Like:

```
@NotEmpty
@KeyFormat
private String key;
```

What would be the best way to reduce duplications? Let's say wrap `Client` by `ClientBean`.. Extends Client by ClientBean.. to be able to use annotation advantage.

Comment: Use `#{clientBean.client.key}` directly in your JSF code.

Answer (score 0):

Your ClientBean has field Client:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ClientBean{
    private Client client;

    private Client getClient(){
       return client;
    }
}
```

And you can use EL like this #{clientBean.client.name}

If you want to reduce this long EL, you can use JSTL(xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core") :

```
<c:set var="client" value="#{clientBean.client}"/>
```

And your expressions will be like this #{client.name}